# Как вычислить сложность моего алгоритма?

Tags: golang, рекурсия

Продолжаю разбираться с рекурсией

Задача: определить является ли N простым числом.

Условие: использовать только рекурсию.

Мое решение(в комментах пояснение моей логики):

```
package main

func main() {
    rec(890, 1, 0) //Output: NO
    println()
}

// функция имеет допущение, что n>1(т.е рассчитывает на здравый смысл вызывающего)
// для n<=1 результат будет неправильным(YES).
func rec(n, d, c int) {
    // если делитель дошел до делимого,
    //то очевидно, что если они равны то делятся без остатка и
    //делимость проверять не нужно. Просто выходим из функции.
    //этот случай означает, что от d>1 до n делителей не найдено.
    //значит n делится только на себя и на 1
    if d > n {
        print("YES")
        return
    }
    //поиск делителя для n в диапазоне от 2 до n
    if n%d == 0 && d > 1 {
        //увеличиваем счетчик делителей
        c++
        //если d еще не дошел до n, а уже нашел делитель(c>0),
        //то число точно составное, дальнейшие проверки не имеют смысла
        //говорим что число составное и выходим из функции.
        if c > 1 || (n%2 == 0 && n > 2) {
            print("NO")
            return
        }
    n=int(math.Sqrt(float64(n))) //так код продолжает работать, но делает это быстрее, 
    //хоть и нет гарантии что правильно рассчитывает. Но пока что ни разу не ошибся
    }
    //рекурсивно проверяем является ли d+1 делителем n
    //рекурсивный вызов будет происходит до тех пор,
    //пока c<1 || (d<n && n%d!=0 && (n>2 && n%2!=0))
    rec(n, d+1, c)
}
```

Вопрос1: Можно ли обойтись без такого количества if(насколько сильно намудрил)?

Вопрос2: Как рассчитать сложность этого алгоритма? Как сделать его не линейным

Вопрос3: На слишком больших числах, например `1284762193641112317` получаю stack overflow. в чем проблема? Мое предположение - слишком много рекурсивных вызовов. Но как это исправить?

UPD:

Добавил в код фрагмент

```
n = int(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))
```

И код продолжает работать. Придумал такое,  в поисках способа сократить количество рекурсивных вызовов, а с таким фрагментом, в каждом вызове n уменьшается до своего корня.

Comment: 2. Сложность алгоритма линейная.

Comment: 3. Какой размер стека в исполнимом файле? Какой размер записи активации для `rec`? Чему равно их отношение? Сколько памяти на вашем компьютере?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy 1: 890  не простое число.  Код правильно это показывает +оно еще и четное поэтому отметается как четное без рекурсии вообще.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy понял почему вопрос про 890. Исправил вопрос

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy 889

Comment: Код работает. Можно упростить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно сделать ваш код более традиционным, стандартным.
2. Сложность кода линейная. Строка с корнем квадратным помогает если *n* не простое. В противном случае надо сделать около *n* рекурсивных вызовов. Поэтому сложность пропорциональна *n*.
3. Количество рекурсивных вызовов ограничивается объемом стека. Если его не хватает, программа падает с ошибкой. На моей машине под стек выделен один гигабайт. Простые около 10 миллионов обрабатываются, после 100 миллионов переполняют стек.

Число *n* простое, если оно имеет ровно два делителя: единицу и само себя. Если число составное, то оно имеет вид *n = pq*. Пусть *p ≤ q*, тогда *p* не превосходит корня квадратного из *n*. По этой причине достаточно проверять делители только до *√n*.

В коде ниже проверка *d ≤ √n* заменена на *d ≤ n / d*. Второе выражение обходится без извлечения корня и переполнения, которое возможно в случае проверки *d * d ≤ n*.

Для уменьшения глубины стека в качестве делителей пробуются только двойка и нечётные числа. Глубина стека приблизительно равна *√n / 2*.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func isPrimeIter(n, d uint) bool {
    if d > n / d {
        return true
    }
    if n % d == 0 {
        return false
    }
    return isPrimeIter(n, d + 2)
}

func isPrime(n uint) bool {
    if n < 2 {
        return false
    }
    if n == 2 {
        return true
    }
    return n % 2 != 0 && isPrimeIter(n, 3)
}

func main() {
    var n uint
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    println(isPrime(n))
}
```

> ```
> $ time echo 1000000000000037 | go run is-prime.go
> true
>
> real  0m3.341s
> user  0m3.104s
> sys   0m0.312s
> ```

Ограниченная память под стек не позволяет обработать весь диапазон чисел `uint`. Я так и не выяснил, поддерживает ли Go оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии. Кто-то пишет что нет, кто-то пишет что да. Возможно поддержка появилась, но у меня старый компилятор. Если вы разбираетесь в вопросе, напишите комментарий - версия моего компилятора `go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64`. Так или иначе `isPrimeIter` написан в стиле разрешающем оптимизацию - рекурсивный вызов последний в теле функции, а стек всё равно переполняется.

Не полагаясь на компилятор можно сократить потребную глубину стека заменив линейную рекурсию на древовидную. При этом глубина стека сократится до логарифма.

Функция `isPrimeIter(n, d1, d2 uint) bool` проверяет что *n* не делится ни на один из делителей в полуинтервале *[d<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>)*. Проверяются только нечётные делители не превосходящие *√n*. Если в интервале только одно нечётное число (*d<sub>1</sub> + 2 = d<sub>2</sub>*), делается проверка на делимость. Иначе интервал разбивается примерно пополам и делаются два рекурсивных вызова `isPrimeIter`. Несложно доказать что глубина рекурсии не превосходит *log<sub>2</sub>(d<sub>2</sub> - d<sub>1</sub>)*. Максимальное значение логарифма для `uint` - *64*.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func ceilOdd(n uint) uint {
    return n + 1 - n % 2
}

func isPrimeIter(n, d1, d2 uint) bool {
    if d1 > n / d1 {
        return true
    }
    if d1 + 2 == d2 {
        return n % d1 != 0
    }
    d := ceilOdd((d1 + d2) / 2)
    return isPrimeIter(n, d1, d) && isPrimeIter(n, d, d2)
}

func isPrime(n uint) bool {
    if n < 2 {
        return false
    }
    if n == 2 {
        return true
    }
    return n % 2 != 0 && isPrimeIter(n, 3, ceilOdd(n / 2 + 2))
}

func main() {
    var n uint
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    println(isPrime(n))
}
```

> ```
> $ time echo 1000000000000037 | go run is-prime.go
> true
>
> real  0m0.687s
> user  0m0.756s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Самые "трудные" числа для этой программы - простые и квадраты простых. В обоих случаях можно уложиться в минуту.

Самое большое простое число *< 2<sup>64</sup>*:

> ```
> $ time echo 18446744073709551557 | go run is-prime.go
> true
>
> real  0m59.858s
> user  0m59.144s
> sys   0m0.076s
> ```

Самый большой квадрат простого числа *< 2<sup>64</sup>* (*18446744030759878681 = 4294967291<sup>2</sup>*):

> ```
> $ time echo 18446744030759878681 | go run is-prime.go
> false
>
> real  0m59.607s
> user  0m58.996s
> sys   0m0.064s
> ```

Comment: Рекурсивные вычисления не требуют быть на стеке. Можно, например, рекурсивный вызов отправлять в горутину - будет очень медленно, нужно больше памяти, надо думать, как вернуть результат, но зато обходится ограничения на глубину стэка.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, есть традиционные методы для сокращения глубины стека. Прибегать к горутинам не обязательно. И скорость не пострадает.

Comment: "есть традиционные методы для сокращения глубины стека." - если имеется ввиду частичное разворачивание рекурсии в цикл, то противоречит условиям задачи. Так-то можно сократить глубину до единственного вызова.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, обновил ответ.